# Select2 - Add pending tag after losing focus

Tags: jquery-select2

I am trying to use select2 for creating tags, but when I'm writing a new tag and I lose the focus of the field (click somewhere else, for example) what I was writing gets deleted.

Is there a way that after losing focus to the input of the select2, a new tag gets created?

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](https://select2.github.io/options.html):

```
$('select').select2({
  selectOnClose: true
});
```

This will capture the selection and create a tag if the user clicks elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the browser problem that i've seen.

It seems that the tags option doesn't work correctly on ie11.

I don't have the same behavior between ie11 and chrome (and edge). If you check the example https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags with ie, it is not possible to add tag. You can start taping letter but you lose the focus immediately. 
Everything works on Chrome and Edge.

Is it this sort of problem, you've got.

Comment: Ran into this exact issue today & haven't yet found a solution.

Comment: Filed the following issue (for posterity's sake): [https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4525](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4525)